# Logging Google Chrome Info To Terminal - AppleScript

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, applescript

I am trying to log the contents of Google Chrome to terminal. To do this, I frankensteined a few example programs together. Yet, I have an issue. The command that I am using to log the title and URL to terminal gives me unwanted output.

Commands:

```
log (theTab's URL)
log (theTab's title)
```

The following command should log the tabs URL and title. Here is an example:

```
www.example.com
Example
```

Here is an image of the output:

[image: Image of output.]

Here is all the code in case you need it:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with theWindow in every window
        set theTabIndex to 0
        log theWindow
        repeat with theTab in every tab of theWindow
            set theTabIndex to theTabIndex + 1
            log theTabIndex
            log (theTab's URL)
            log (theTab's title)
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Here is all the output (sorry that it is kinda large):

[image: All the output.]

By the way, if you can think of a way to do this without AppleScript, please tell me.

Resources:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/applescript

Thanks,
Base

Comment: Why Terminal?  Why not a text file?

Comment: I am going to use the output in a bash script.

Comment: Well, since the output direct to Terminal is a problem, I recommend you try to write the output to a text file, at least to see if it is in a more useful format.  If so, you can use the script to read the file before execution.